# magento 2 unable to set the values for product collection using service contract from custom module?

Tags: magento2, product, module, api, methods

I am trying to form a custom format for product collection(getList) using service-contract concept in magento 2 i am able to add keys but i am unable to add values to the response object can you please suggest me

app/code/Ewall/Test/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd"> <route url="/V1/productlist" method="GET">
        <service class="Ewall\Test\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

app/code/Ewall/Test/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Ewall\Test\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" type="Ewall\Test\Model\ProductRepository"/>
    <preference for="Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults" />
    <preference for="Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductInterface" type="Ewall\Test\Model\Product"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Ewall/Test/Api/Data/ProductInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Ewall\Test\Api\Data;


interface ProductInterface 
{
    /**#@+
     * Constants defined for keys of  data array
     */
    const SKU = 'sku';

    const NAME = 'name';

    const PRICE = 'price';

    const WEIGHT = 'weight';

    const STATUS = 'status';

    const DESCRIPTION = 'description';

    const BRAND = 'brand';

    const POSITION = 'position';

    const URL = 'url';

    const URL_KEY = 'url_key';

    const EXPRESS_DELIVERY = 'express_delivery';

    const ITEM_COLLECTION = 'item_collection';

    const IS_OFFER = 'is_offer';

    const OFFER_TEXT = 'offer_text';

    const IMAGE = 'image';

    const CHILDREN_DATA = 'children_data';

    /**#@-*/

    /**
     * Product id
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId();

    /**
     * Set product id
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setId($id);

    /**
     * Product name
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getName();

    /**
     * Set product name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name);

    /**
     * Product sku
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSku();

    /**
     * Set product sku
     *
     * @param string $sku
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSku($sku);

    /**
     * Product description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription();

    /**
     * Set product description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDescription($description);

    /**
     * Product brand
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBrand();

    /**
     * Set product brand
     *
     * @param string $brand
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBrand($brand);

    /**
     * Product position
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getposition();

    /**
     * Set product position
     *
     * @param string $position
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setposition($position);

    /**
     * Product url_key
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlKey();

    /**
     * Set product url_key
     *
     * @param string $url_key
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUrlKey($url_key);

    /**
     * Product url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl();

    /**
     * Set product url
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUrl($url);

    /**
     * Product express_delivery
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExpressDelivery();

    /**
     * Set product express_delivery
     *
     * @param string $express_delivery
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setExpressDelivery($express_delivery);

    /**
     * Product item_collection
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getItemCollection();

    /**
     * Set product item_collection
     *
     * @param string $item_collection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setItemCollection($item_collection);

    /**
     * Product status
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getStatus();

    /**
     * Set product status
     *
     * @param int $status
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStatus($status);

    /**
     * Product is_offer
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIsOffer();

    /**
     * Set product is_offer
     *
     * @param string $is_offer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIsOffer($is_offer);

    /**
     * Product offer_text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOfferText();

    /**
     * Set product offer_text
     *
     * @param string $offer_text
     * @return string
     */
    public function setOfferText($offer_text);

    /**
     * Store id
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getStoreId();

    /**
     * Set store id
     *
     * @param int $store_id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStoreId($store_id);

    /**
     * Product image
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImage();

    /**
     * Set product image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setImage($image);

    /**
     * Product children_data[]
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getChildrenData();

    /**
     * Set product children_data
     *
     * @param array $children_data
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setChildrenData($children_data);

    /**
     * Product weight
     *
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function getWeight();

    /**
     * Set product weight
     *
     * @param float $weight
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setWeight($weight);


}
```

app/code/Ewall/Test/Api/Data/ProductSearchResultsInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Ewall\Test\Api\Data;


interface ProductSearchResultsInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResultsInterface
{
    /**
     * Get attributes list.
     *
     * @return \Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductInterface[]
     */
    public function getItems();

    /**
     * Set attributes list.
     *
     * @param \Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductInterface[] $items
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setItems(array $items);
}
```

app/code/Ewall/Test/Api/ProductRepositoryInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Ewall\Test\Api;


interface ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Get product list
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return \Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface
     */
    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria);
}

<?php

namespace Ewall\Test\Model;

use Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\ConnectionException;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DeadlockException;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\LockWaitException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 */
class ProductRepository implements \Ewall\Test\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $optionRepository;

    /**
     * @var Product[]
     */
    protected $instances = [];

    /**
     * @var Product[]
     */
    protected $instancesById = [];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper
     */
    protected $initializationHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $searchResultsFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
     */
    protected $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    protected $resourceModel;

    /**
     * @var Product\Initialization\Helper\ProductLinks
     */
    protected $linkInitializer;

    /**
     * @var Product\LinkTypeProvider
     */
    protected $linkTypeProvider;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $attributeRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $metadataService;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter
     */
    protected $extensibleDataObjectConverter;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem
     */
    protected $fileSystem;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface
     */
    protected $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor
     */
    protected $mediaGalleryProcessor;

    /**
     * @var CollectionProcessorInterface
     */
    private $collectionProcessor;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $cacheLimit = 0;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
     */
    private $serializer;

    /**
     * ProductRepository constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper $initializationHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory
     * @param ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository
     * @param ResourceModel\Product $resourceModel
     * @param Product\Initialization\Helper\ProductLinks $linkInitializer
     * @param Product\LinkTypeProvider $linkTypeProvider
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $metadataServiceInterface
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
     * @param Product\Option\Converter $optionConverter
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor
     * @param CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor [optional]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json|null $serializer
     * @param int $cacheLimit [optional]
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper $initializationHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resourceModel,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Initialization\Helper\ProductLinks $linkInitializer,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkTypeProvider $linkTypeProvider,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $metadataServiceInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Converter $optionConverter,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor,
        CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null,
        $cacheLimit = 1000
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->initializationHelper = $initializationHelper;
        $this->searchResultsFactory = $searchResultsFactory;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->resourceModel = $resourceModel;
        $this->linkInitializer = $linkInitializer;
        $this->linkTypeProvider = $linkTypeProvider;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->metadataService = $metadataServiceInterface;
        $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter = $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor = $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;
        $this->collectionProcessor = $collectionProcessor ?: $this->getCollectionProcessor();
        $this->serializer = $serializer ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class);
        $this->cacheLimit = (int)$cacheLimit;
    }

    /**
     * Get key for cache
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getCacheKey($data)
    {
        $serializeData = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (is_object($value)) {
                $serializeData[$key] = $value->getId();
            } else {
                $serializeData[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        $serializeData = $this->serializer->serialize($serializeData);
        return sha1($serializeData);
    }

    /**
     * Add product to internal cache and truncate cache if it has more than cacheLimit elements.
     *
     * @param string $cacheKey
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
     * @return void
     */
    private function cacheProduct($cacheKey, \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product)
    {
        $this->instancesById[$product->getId()][$cacheKey] = $product;
        $this->instances[$product->getSku()][$cacheKey] = $product;

        if ($this->cacheLimit && count($this->instances) > $this->cacheLimit) {
            $offset = round($this->cacheLimit / -2);
            $this->instancesById = array_slice($this->instancesById, $offset, null, true);
            $this->instances = array_slice($this->instances, $offset);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');

        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);

        $collection->load();

        $collection->addCategoryIds();
        $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
        $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
        $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());

       /* foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {
            $this->cacheProduct(
                $this->getCacheKey(
                    [
                        false,
                        $product->hasData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::STORE_ID) ? $product->getStoreId() : null
                    ]
                ),
                $product
            );
        }
*/
        return $searchResult;
    }

    /**
     * Clean internal product cache
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function cleanCache()
    {
        $this->instances = null;
        $this->instancesById = null;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection processor
     *
     * @deprecated 101.1.0
     * @return CollectionProcessorInterface
     */
    private function getCollectionProcessor()
    {
        if (!$this->collectionProcessor) {
            $this->collectionProcessor = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                'Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\ProductCollectionProcessor'
            );
        }
        return $this->collectionProcessor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls check here https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-custom-rest-api/

Comment: thanks for the providing link @Abdul but i would like to add methods for product

Comment: Yes, I have created custom rest api methods for product. Can you please explain in details?

Comment: can you please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207244/magento-2-api-want-to-implement-configurable-product-collection-based-on-custom

Comment: actually i need to implement the product details api with the custom keys and values can you please help me thanks how to we do?

Comment: are you need products create api with your format right?

Comment: yes exactly abdul i need the response object based on that format. please guide me i was struck from the past 3 days

Comment: You can just overwrite this class and extend this class so you can have access of your custom method as well as core methods

Answer (score 1):

I think, your intention was to return instances of `Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductInterface`, but there is no any integration with this interface.

The following steps should help you:

- Introduce some implementation of `Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductInterface` and add an appropriate preference to `di.xml`
- Convert `Catalog\Model\Product` items received from `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::getItems` to DTO from previous step. This could be done using factory, that receives original data and creates your object based on this data.
- Pass converted items to search result

The resulting code from repository should look like:

```
$yourItems = [];
foreach ($collection->getItems() as $originalProduct) {
    /** @var \Ewall\Test\Api\Data\ProductInterface */
    $yourItems[] = $yourItemFactory->create($originalProduct->getData());
}
$searchResult->setItems($yourItems);
```

Comment: hi @andrey please confirm whether we have to change this marked code? https://prnt.sc/hv2g7u

Comment: Hi. It depends on your needs. The caching makes sense if there are multiple calls to the repository in the same HTTP request. Otherwise, it's completely redundant.